# add a menu in a field

Tags: routes

Does anyone know if there is a custom field type that allows you to assign a menu inside of the field? What I would like to do is add a list menu inside of the body field. I know I could do it manually through html but I would rather add it as a menu type.

Comment: But do you want to choose the menu while editing the node?

Comment: Yes, when a new node is created I would like to dynamically add the node to the menu.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to you is use `list` as type and select list as widget then in select list value add something like below :

```
<a  href="#">link1</a>|<a  href="#">link1</a>
<a  href="#">link2</a>|<a  href="#">link2</a>
<a  href="#">link3</a>|<a  href="#">link3</a>
```

and after node saved it is completely link .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Drupal 7.

You could try to embed the [menu field module](https://drupal.org/project/menufield). Add it to a content type and then to a piece of content. Finally clear the cache (or you won't see anything).